# iOS Bridge for Window Phone crash on addSubview

Tags: ios, windows-10-universal, code-conversion

I'm using Microsoft iOS Bridge to convert an app from iOS to Windows Phone, but UIKit.dll crash when I try to add a View on the Windows object of the AppDelegate.

```
[self.window addSubview: webView];//UIKIT.dll crash: Access violation reading location 0x00000050.
```